# Parse.com with multiple live queries best practices

Tags: parse-platform

I’m using multiple live queries in my js app and was wondering what are the best practices on this subject.

I did read somewhere that opening multiple websockets at a time should be avoided. What are the recommendations using the Parse.com live queries ?

Currently, I'm launching 3 times the following function (and changing the document and function name)

```
     startWebserver1: async function(param) {
            Parse.initialize(this.parse.initialize)
            Parse.serverURL = this.parse.serverURL

            const snapshots = Parse.Object.extend("myDocument1");
            const query = new Parse.Query(snapshots)
            const subscriptionSnapshots = await query.subscribe()

            subscriptionSnapshots.on('open', () => {
                console.log(' -> Snapshots subscription opened');
            });
}
```

Comment: If you are using the SDK to open the live queries, it will automatically manage that for you and will use a single web socket for all live queries.

Comment: Ok, but how should I do it in my code ? should I query.subscribe() 3 times or is there a way to make one single query for all 3 documents ?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the queries. Maybe if you can share them. Anyways, I'd say if it is possible to easily aggregate the 3 queries into a single not complex query, I'd go with a single one.

Comment: I just edited my question with the function. I'm basically launching 3 functions and was wondering how I can make one single query.subscribe() to my 3 documents in once.

Comment: Do you mean three different collections, like myDocument1, myDocument2, and myDocument3? Because they are different collections, you will need different subscriptions.

Comment: Yes 3 different collections. Ok, so it means I need to open 3 subscription/ live queries, correct ?

Comment: Yes. That's the only way.